# Visualizing multiple tables

Tags: r, data-visualization

In four different experiments, I ran two programs `A` and `B` with different parameter setteings `a`, `b`, and `c`. Target variable is kind of time -- lower Target value means higher performance. I know the reasons why program `A` is better than `B` or vice-versa. Currently I am representing this data as tables in my latex document. However, I am not happy with this. I would like to provide a single figure which could show the difference between the parameter setteings effectively, and would be easy for the reades to get an idea of why `A` is better than `B` or vice-versa in a particular experiment.

Moreover, the units of the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c` are not the same. Thats why I don't like to use barplots for this problem.

It would be great if some one help for drawing a nice graph in R. Thank you.

```
Experiment-1
program & a & b & c & Target
A & 0.86  & 151 & 7 & 27 
B & 0.82 & 168 & 114 & 48 

Experiment-2
program & a & b & c & Target
A & 0.88 & 23530 & 67 & 154 
B & 0.79 & 23090 & 34 & 82 

Experiment-3
program & a & b & c & Target
A & 0.19  & 7855 & 172 & 53
B & 0.16 & 7398 & 189 & 104    

Experiment-4
program & a & b & c & Target
A & 0.30  & 5062 &301&  250 
B & 0.21 & 8797 & 443 & 198
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to play around with, next time do yourself a favor and don't make us figure out your data - provide us with a sample! :)

```
library(ggplot2)
cols <- c("a","b","c","target","program","experiment")
a <- c(0.86,0.88,0.19,0.30)
b <- c(151,23530,7855,5062)
c1 <- c(7,67,172,301)
targt <- c(27,154,53,250)
a2 <- c(0.82,168,114,48)
b2 <- c(168,23090,7398,8797)
c2 <- c(114,34,189,443)
targt2 <- c(48,82,104,198)
df <- data.frame(c(a,a2),
c(b,b2),
c(c1,c2),
c(targt,targt2),
program=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)), 
experiment=rep(1:4,4))
colnames(df) <- cols
df <- melt(df, c("program","experiment","target"))

ggplot(df, aes(target, value, color=variable)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(program ~ experiment, scales="free_x")
ggplot(df, aes(target, value, color=program)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(variable ~ experiment, scales="free")
```

Comment: Thank you. Sure, next time, I will provide a sample of my data. BTW, could you tell me how can I increase size of the points and also represent them with different pch values.

Comment: @kkp If the units of measurement are of no interest, why not simply showing the target difference A-B for each condition (superimposed on the same plot for the 4 labelled experiments)?

Comment: @kkp, actually, that's a good point. If the units don't matter, you could scale each one and have it all in one graph.

Comment: You can add a size argument inside `geom_point(size=3)`. I'm not sure what you mean by represent them with different pch values. You mean vary size by some additional variable? It would look something like `geom_text(aes(size=pch_values))`